# PWA serviceWorker not always registered

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

We have in-house built CMS and recently we added PWA to it. Now, when accessing the home page www.ourdomain.com everything is fine, but when accessing an article, we are a news website, someting like www.ourdomain.com/section/article a message appears:

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was
>   gwreceived when fetching the script.

First the scope was

./

and in that case ServiceWorker wasn't registered at all.

Now I changed the scope to

/

and not it is registered for the home page but not for any article. I went through docs, reading questions and answers but doesn't seem able to solve this. By they way, PWA installs well on a mobile an works well.

Comment: you might wanna post some code of your registration script,

Answer (score 0):

Your service worker js file should preferably be in your root public directory of your app since you're just starting out with PWAs, and specifying the correct scope is essential, Here's a perfect example of installing your service worker from [Google PWA guide](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker).

1. `main.js`

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
  });
}
```

2. `service-worker.js`

Expecting that you have `/service-worker.js` and `main.js` in your root directory, and if you get to work with manifest, you render the same scope as your [start_url](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/manifest-contains-start_url)

You can try the above installation snippet on your app public root directory.

Comment: Thank you. The js file is in the root directory, indeed. I just noticed something interesting: while console in Chrome says that everything is fine for every page, web.dev says that serviceWorker is registered just for the home page. So, those are conflicting information and I'm not sure is console right or web.dev.